# Creating file dynamically and downloading onto user's computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file, download

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in Rails:

Have a link on the webpage. When the user clicks on the link, the controller generates a file dynamically (say, a text file that contains a single random number between 1 and 10), and the file is downloaded onto the user's computer. The file might be temporarily stored on the server, but it shouldn't be permanently there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `send_data` in the controller:

```
send_data("4", :filename => "my_awesome_file")
```

If you already have the file on the server, you can use `send_file` instead

```
send_file(filepath, :filename => "my_awesome_file")
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. This is what I have in one of my apps:

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController

  def download
    # ...
    send_file CSVConstructor::Constructor.new(...).to_zip 
  end

end
```

The `download` action takes params submitted from a form and sends them to a custom class that generates a few files, packages them as a zip, and returns the file path. You'll have to figure out the best way to generate files for your own app, but I would recommend something similar - branching the functionality into a separate class helps keep your controller light.